# Using IF, AND, and VLOOKUP functions together

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to mark a list of about 1500 sports clubs as active or inactive in a certain initiative.

In sheet 1, I have the list of clubs signed up to the initiative in column A. In column B of this same sheet I have a 0, 1, or 2 (with cell icon conditional formatting) to indicate whether or not the club is pending (0), currently progressing (1) or completed (2) the initiative. 
Sheet 2 contains the full list of clubs that could potentially avail of the initiative in column C. In column D of sheet 2 I want the word "active" or "inactive" based on whether or not the Club name appears in Sheet 1, column A and also whether it is marked as pending, progressing or complete in sheet 1 column B. Essentially, any club that is listed in sheet 1 Column A with the adjacent cell in column B containing a value less than 2 should be marked as active in sheet 2 column D, and every other Club should be marked inactive.

I have been trying to achieve this through a combination of the IF, AND and VLOOKUP functions but I don't think I am on the right track.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!!

Comment: If I understand (and remember) correctly, you shouldn't need AND as the VLOOKUP should fail (return #NA?) if the lookup value isn't found.

Comment: Also, since it was mentioned in your last question as well: Definitely try to add sample data in the future. It helps tremendously when answering questions and will invite more people to help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following formula for the first cell (D2), and fill down.

```
=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$2000,2,FALSE),0)<2,"Inactive","Active")
```

To break the formula down:
The `VLOOKUP` will use the value in Sheet2, C2 (Team Name), search in the range specified on Sheet1, use the second column (B), and find an exact match.

```
VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$2000,2,FALSE)
```

The `IFNA` will return '0' if the team name is not matched.

```
IFNA(value,0)
```

Finally, the `IF` will return "Inactive" if the returned value is less than two, otherwise "Active" if 2 (or higher, but this shouldn't be a possibility given input).

```
IF(logical_test < 2,"Inactive","Active")
```